# Simulating Mouseclick on Mac

Tags: python, applescript, hotkeys

How can I do this? Specifically, I want to simulate those mouseclicks at certain coords in a flash window on a hotkey.

I did applescript, with `click at (x,y)`, but the script could identify anything in the flash window, so it failed.

I tried automator, but it's too clumsy to do on a hotkey.

I heard that python can do this, but I don't know how to do it like  this.

Help would be appreciated,

-Odinulf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have released a command line utility MouseTools for this. You can run that using applescript if you like... download and see examples [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html).

Comment: Great. I released it so it could help others so I'm glad it works for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is something like this:

http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/

python-uinput

They also have a github page that will probably be useful to you - https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/python-uinput